# Apply function on all but K columns in a dataframe (similarity of a vector to each member of the df, without id column)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df and vector:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id = [0,1,2], a=[4,5,6], b=[22,11.1,-5]))
vec = pd.DataFrame(dict(id = [90], a=[9], b=[6.4]))
```

I want to calculate a similarity of vec to all vectors in df, without the id column.
I know I can hold out the columns, calculate the similarity and glue it back.

```
df_id = df['id']
vec_id = vec['id']

df_wo_id = df.drop(['id'], axis=1)
vec_wo_id = vec.drop(['id'], axis=1)
df_wo_id['similarity'] = df_wo_id.apply(lambda row: 1 - cosine(row, vec_wo_id),axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df_id, df_wo_id], axis=1)
```

Is there another approach to apply some function like the one above simpler (maybe using some masks)?

Comment: what function `cosine` do you use? the one from scipy? in this case your code does not work. shouldn't the `apply` have the parameter `axis=1`?

Comment: @Ben.T I have fixed the axis part, but it's not the focus. I just wanted to understand if there is a simpler approach.

Comment: I understand cosine is not the focus, but if you look for better way to do your operation it does. Anyway, the given answer by Fabien seems a good way for the use of `apply` with your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify a mask beforehand and use it in the apply method:

```py
mask = ~df.columns.isin(['id'])
df['similiarity'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 - cosine(row[mask], vec.loc[:,mask]),axis=1)
```